# TypeScript typings give me "index.d.ts is not a module"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am getting *File node_modules/@types/webrtc/index.d.ts is not a module* with this code:

```
import * as webrtc from "webrtc";
const peerConnection1 = new RTCPeerConnection();
```

I have installed the typings using `npm i @types/webrtc --save-dev`. Hovering over `RTCPeerConnection` in `const peerConnection1 = new RTCPeerConnection();` display type annotations in Visual Studio Code so at least the code editor sees the types. Running `tsc` (or `webpack` with `ts-loader`) fails with the error.

I have tried `npm i webrtc --save` in a misguided attempt for solving this, but it did not change anything and I really only want the typings anyway, WebRTC is right there in the browser, I don't need a package for that. (Support aside.)

The `index.d.ts` file indeed is not a module, it just references two other files with interfaces in them. So I thought to remove `import * as webrtc from "webrtc";` hoping the typings will still be visible by `tsc` somehow. (But that's impossible since I exclude `node_modules` in TypeScript config file.) When I do that `RTCPeerConnection` is no longer recognized.

Adding `/// <reference src="node_modules/@types/webrtc/" />` did not help, `tsc` says *Invalid reference directive syntax*.

You can view a repository with minimal repro [here on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/TomasHubelbauer/qr-signalling-channel). I am not too well versed in TypeScript typings acquisition so please forgive my ignorance if I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

webrtc is part of the browser; you're trying to import a module. Simply import the (typings) library:

```
import "webrtc";
```

you may need to use `"moduleResolution": "node"` in the compiler options.

Alternatively use the `"types": ["webrtc"]` compiler option and the compiler will automatically load those types up for you.

Answer (score 147):

In vscode

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>  > Developer: Reload Window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Why does this work and restarting vsCode does not?

Comment: Wow. I was having fits with VS Code giving this error about the React index.d.ts when my app was compiling just fine. Restarts of VS Code had no effect but this did. Wish I knew why.

Answer (score 17):

You probably want to add

```
"types": ["webrtc"]
```

to your `tsconfig.json`, or less preferrably, to use

```
/// <reference types="webrtc" />
```

in your source files. Here's an example of it in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,

        "types": ["webrtc"]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

This tells TypeScript it should include `webrtc` declarations in your build

Comment: Don't set `types` or else *only* those types will get loaded — usually everything in `node_modules/@types` is loaded, and this will prevent that behaviour. You simply need to `npm i @types/webrtc` these days.

Comment: @aendrew that isn't entirely true because it depends on where your `tsconfig.json` is placed relative to your `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Yeah this just makes TS not load any other types, even for my local app modules it now spews out thousands of errors about missing types...

Answer (score 11):

No need to import anything, run following:

1. `npm install --save @types/webrtc`
2. update tsconfig.json -

   "types": [
         "@types/webrtc"
       ]

Comment: This will make it so that only the webrtc types are imported. Don't update tsconfig.json.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/...` is preferred - normally, TS is not used in production

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to add a new declaration file `*.d.ts` in your module, i.e.:

```
declare module 'my-module';
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was getting this error message with an `index.d.ts` file generated by the TypeScript compiler.

The problem was that I’d forgotten to specify any `import` or `export` declarations in the source `.ts` file. I removed the original `module.export = {…}` bit when porting from `.js` to `.ts`, and hadn’t yet replaced it.

This is how [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) define a ‘module’ (emphasis added):

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, **any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module**. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

Adding an `export` to the things I intended to export turned the `index.d.ts` into a module, clearing the error.

Comment: Mine was related in that the generated file didn't have an export, but my issue was because I was using `outFile` with a ESM (NodeNext) module type. Switching to `outDir` fixed things for my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar error on VS code editor. Simply, closing and opening VSCode again solved the problem for me.

Comment: cant belive I didnt think of this (facepalm)

Comment: Welp, this fixed it for me too

Answer (score 2):

`/// <reference types="@types/<your_types_module>" />`

You may or may not want to do this depending on your build and style needs, but this seems to be the quick (and dirty) fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a corrupted dependency, deleting the module and `npm install` did the work.

Comment: This unfortunately could be a solution sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I forked a library, renamed it in package.json but didn't rename this line in its .d.ts file (the file pointed to by `"types":` in package.json):

```
declare module "package-name" {
```

to

```
declare module "my-forked-package-name" {
```

Answer (score -6):

use require

```
const webRtc = require('webrtc');
```

and you import should be good to go