# How to use jQuery Plugin with Angular 5 and TypeScript 2.8.1?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular5, typescript2.8

I want to import jQuery in an Angular 5 project using TypeScript 2.8.1.
I follow [Ervin Llojku solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653848/1655155) but this does not the trick :

> Install jquery with npm
>
> ```
> npm install --save jquery
> ```
>
> Install jquery with npm
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
> ```
>
> Add scripts to .angular-cli.json
>
> ```
> "apps": [{
>   ...
>   "scripts": [
>     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
>   ],
>   ...
> }]
> ```

I also try to add these imports in **app.module.ts** or in component :

```
import * as $ 'jquery';
```

Whatever I try TypeScript compiler throws this error :

```
Error:(7, 15) TS2497: Module ''jquery'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441400/1655155) and I replaced

```
import * as $ 'jquery';
```

with

```
import 'jquery';
```

in **app.module.ts** and everything seems to be OK.

Still I don't know if this error was due to Angular 5 or TypeScript 2.8.1...

or maybe to the **tsconfig.json** generated by Angular :

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "moduleResolution": "node",
}
```