# TypeScript not finding the types in @types

Tags: node.js, typescript, webgl2

I am trying to import some types from `@types/webgl2` in my project.
I have followed every bit of advice mentioned here:
[TypeScript typings give me "index.d.ts is not a module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441252/typescript-typings-give-me-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module)

Added this to the top: `import 'webgl2';`

- I have made sure "`modeResolution`" is "`true`" in `tsconfig.json`
- I added a line `"types":["webgl2"]` to my `tsconfig.json`
- Added  `"@types/webgl2": "0.0.4"` to both `devDependencies` and `dependencies` in `package.json`.
- Did an npm install in my project folder:

> ```
> npm WARN package.json webgl@0.0.1 No README data
> npm WARN package.json Dependency '@types/webgl2' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using '@types/webgl2@0.0.4' from  dependencies
> ```

I can easily see `webgl2` in `node_modules/@types` and I can also see the declaration for all errored symbols under:

```
declare var WebGl2RenderingContext {
```

and I still get these errors:

```
(multiple lines)
Cannot find name 'WebGl2RenderingContext'. Did you mean 'WebGL2RenderingContext'?
```

Corresoonding to:

```
const format = WebGl2RenderingContext.RED;
```

Answer (score 4):

Resolved by fixing spelling mistakes.

Comment: Young kids always as "Do you have to be good at math to be a scripting language programmer?". My answer is always "Nope, just typing and spelling".

Answer (score 3):

In your tsconfig set the typeRoot:

```
{
     "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For NG9'ers, try, deleting your package-lock.json file, then:

```
npm i crypto
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had an issue where `types` was specified in `tsconfig` so some types weren't automatically added to the global scope.

So the package in question was `@types/dom-webcodecs` and I added this to tsconfig like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "dom-webcodecs",
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

and after that I could access the types.

This is different than typeRoots which another answer talks about. You can explore the difference [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) if need be.

Comment: This might also require a restart of the IDE to work